# Which FPGA board is suitable for implementing face recognition (neural network)?

Tags: neural-network, fpga, face-recognition

I want to implement face recognition system on FPGA board. The pre-processing is done off chip. So the input will be feature matrix extracted from image. Topology details are as follows :-

No of Input Neuron - 250

No of Hidden Neuron - 25

No of Output Neurons - 40

Activation function - tan-sigmoid

Learning Algorithm - Scaled Conjugate Gradient Algorithm

Answer (score 0):

We recently implemented a neural-network for face recognition on a [SoCkit board](http://www.terasic.com.tw/cgi-bin/page/archive.pl?Language=English&CategoryNo=167&No=816). The topology is as the following:

No of Input Neuron - 8

No of Hidden Neuron - 64

No of Output Neurons - 2

Activation function - ReLU

Synthesis results give us a logic ressources utilization of around 80% for an input image of 512x512. Clearly, if you want to fully parallelized your network, this board isn't the good choice.

To choose the best board for your application, you must check the number of DSP Blocks embedded in the FPGA. I advise you to opt for [this board](http://www.terasic.com.tw/cgi-bin/page/archive.pl?Language=English&CategoryNo=166&No=893&PartNo=1) (a bit expensive) based on an Arria V SoC or its equivalent in no-SoC component.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am just curious. If your image size is 512 * 512. How did you manage to extract a feature matrix of size 8 ? Or am I missing something ?
I am using ORL dataset where each image is 112 * 92 pixel. I used 2D-PCA to dimensionality reduction and the feature matrix is now 112 * 2. So the input becomes 224.

Comment: I used face-detector dataset from E. Culurciello. This dataset gives 32*32 images of faces and backgrounds. In fact, the number of neuron gives the number of output maps, not the matrix size (which is 127*127 for the first layer output: conv 5x5 + max pooling 4x4).